# Creating "noname" class instances

Tags: java, class, instance

So here is my problem. I know one of the simpliest way of creating a new instance of a class is :

```
    ClassName instanceName = new ClassName(); 
    instanceName.methodName(); //executing the method
```

The problem I am facing is this, I want the instances to be created automatically for example when I click a button a new instance is made, how do I do that? Should I create some automated method with iterating variable to create new instances like instance1, instance2 etc.? I also tried to do something like this, already executing the method with creation of a new instance:

```
    (new ClassName()).methodNAme();
```

However I have no access to this new instance, because I don't know how to call/pass it since it has no name.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: seems like `interface` keyword will help you here.

Comment: Do you need access to every instance ever created? Or only the most recent one? (Hint, it's probably the later).

Comment: @VictorSorokin Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Antimony Well for now it is the latter, however I wouldn't mind getting to know about doing that with every instance instead coming back sometime in the future asking about it again.

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you please provide some context with a complete, short example of code? In particular, where are you using this instance? Is it just used in the `onActionPerformed()` callback or is it used elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be reassigned. The variable is a name which can point to different instances at runtime. So you only need a single variable if you only want the most recent instance.

```
ClassName instanceName;

//Create a new instance
instanceName = new ClassName(); 
instanceName.methodName();

//Create a new instance
instanceName = new ClassName(); 
instanceName.methodName(); //Will now use the second instance
```